# Unable to access scanner on nested if condition

Tags: java

The expected output of the code is for a user to guess a randomly generated number between 0 to 100000, and for each guesses he pay $1.00, if the user guesses right he wins $1m, if not he is asked if he want a hint. each hint cost $2.00. so the code continues to run until the user quits the game or wins. the problem with my code is that after asking the user if he wants a hint or not the scanner input code doesn't run.

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int guess, toguess;
    String payOrQuit, yesOrNo;
    double totalSpent = 0.0, hint, value;
    boolean isWon = false, isQuit = false;
    Random rand = new Random();

    while (!isWon && !isQuit) {
      toguess = rand.nextInt(1000000);
      System.out.println("Want to win a million dollars?");
      System.out.println("If so, guess the winning number (a number between 0 and 100000).");
      System.out.print("Insert $1.00 and enter your number or 'q' to quit: ");
      payOrQuit = input.nextLine();
      if (payOrQuit.matches(".*\\d.*")) { // IF pays or quit
        value = Double.parseDouble(payOrQuit);
        System.out.println(toguess);
        System.out.print("Guess a number: ");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        if (guess == toguess) { // IF 2 starts
          System.out.println("YOU WIN!\nYou won $1000000!");
          isWon = true;
        } else {
          totalSpent += value;
          System.out.print("Sorry, good guess,Do you want me to give you a hint (y|n)?");
          yesOrNo = input.nextLine();
          if (yesOrNo.equals("y")) { // IF 3 starts
            System.out.print("Insert $2.00 for the hint! : ");
            hint = input.nextDouble();
            totalSpent += hint;
            if (guess > toguess) {
              System.out.println("Guessed number too high");
            } else {
              System.out.println("Guessed number too low");
            }
          } else {
            System.out.println("amount lost = " + totalSpent);
            isQuit = true;
          } // IF 3 ends
        } // IF 2 ends
      } else {
        System.out.println("amount lost = " + totalSpent);
        isQuit = true;
      } // IF pays or quit ends//
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is some really heavily nested code. You should seriously try to split this code into individual parts and put those into dedicated methods and classes. Do some proper OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of `input.nextInt()` and `input.nextDouble()`.

```
guess = input.nextInt();
```

Change it to

```
guess = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Similarly, also change

```
hint = input.nextDouble();
```

to

```
hint = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());
```

Check [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) for more information.